# Dynamic memory allocation - Malloc

Tags: c, malloc

I try to allocate the memory of the array dynamically using malloc function. The array (d) is composed of two vectors. The code is as follows:

> 

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
   
  int ind;
  int nlfc;
  double x[5], y[5], z[5];
  nlfc=4;
  double **d;
  double dt[3][nlfc];

   d=malloc(4*sizeof(double));
    for(ind=0; ind<nlfc; ind++) {
    d[ind]=malloc(4*sizeof(double));
  }
  x[4]=0;
  y[4]=0;
  z[4]=0;
  x[0]=-1;
  x[1]=0;
  x[2]=1;
  x[3]=0;
  y[0]=0;
  y[1]=-1;
  y[2]=0;
  y[3]=1;
  z[0]=0;
  z[1]=0;
  z[2]=0;
  z[3]=0;
  for (ind=0;ind<nlfc;ind++){
      d[ind][0]=x[ind]-x[4];
      d[ind][1]=y[ind]-y[4];
      d[ind][2]=z[ind]-z[4];
      
   }
 
    for (ind=0;ind<nlfc;ind++){
      printf("%f\n",sizeof(d[ind][1]));     
   }
   
 free(d);

  }
```

The output is as follows:

0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000

But the output needs to be as follows:

-1
0
1
0

So it seems I implemented malloc function in a wrong way. Could you help me how to implement correctly malloc function in this code?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
d=malloc(4*sizeof(double));
```

is wrong, `d` has type `double **`. It should be:

```
d = malloc(4 * sizeof *d);
```

which will allocate space for four pointers to `double`. A handy rule of thumb is to always de-reference the pointer with `sizeof` when calling `malloc()`, never repeat the type since you might get it wrong.

As pointed out in a comment, you must call `free()` exactly once for each pointer returned by all `malloc()` calls, a single call is not enough.

Comment: Using this method to allocate 2D arrays is wrong to begin with. This isn't the only misconception bug in the question, `free(d);` is also wrong. It would have been correct if only one malloc call had been used.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
printf("%f\n",sizeof(d[ind][1]));
```

which means to work out the number of bytes that a `double` takes up (that's 8) then give the integer 8 to printf but tell printf it's actually a `double`, which causes printf to read some garbage `double` from somewhere and print it - apparently 0 in your case (but it could be something else for someone else).

You probably meant:

```
printf("%f\n",d[ind][1]);
```

without `sizeof`.

Also this:

```
d=malloc(4*sizeof(double));
```

should be this:

```
d=malloc(4*sizeof(double*));
//                      ^
//                      |
//                  added a *
```

although I'm not aware of any computer systems where `double` uses *less* bytes than `double*`, so your program does allocate enough bytes either way.

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate a 2d array using a pointer to an array. Just do:

```
double (*d)[4] = calloc(4, sizeof *d);
```

Remember to call `free(d)` when `d` is no longer needed.

Comment: Or less obscure/more self-documenting: `double (*)[4] = malloc( sizeof(double[4][4]) );`

Comment: @Lundin, may I ask why you consider proposed solution obscure/less self-documenting?

Comment: Because array pointers are already quite obscure. To someone not used to them, it might not be obvious that the code is allocating a 4x4 array. `double (*d)[y] = calloc(x, sizeof *d);` is even more obscure. The clearest and theoretically most correct form is `double (*d)[x][y] = malloc( sizeof(double[x][y]) );` but that comes with the extra re-referencing that we wish to avoid for convenience. (Also in this case zero-init from calloc isn't useful, but that's a micro-optimization)